# Google BigQuery - understanding quotas and limits: project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned

Tags: google-bigquery, limit, quota

I ran a query as a batch job that failed with the error
`google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned`

But when I take a look at my current usage it tells me I used almost nothing and none of my free 1TB query limit (I have 2 projects, but both show the same):

[image]

I also set up a dashboard with two metrics that might be of help but I don't quite understand as there is no axis labeling provided:

[image]

Where can I actually see the current status of my "already scanned bytes"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA views can be useful in your case.

You can find details using this link: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring

Comment: Thanks, Yetkin. I took a look at `total_bytes_processed` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` and it gives a rough idea about the free bytes until the limit is reached. Still, it says `daily quotas are replenished at regular intervals throughout the day`, so I can just guess how much I have available. Any idea how I can get this information?

Comment: You can check the Quotas page under IAM&Admin. You can list quotas by service and under each service, you can see the detailed list showing limits and usage.

Comment: Do you mean something different than what I show as an image in my question ( https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas? )? The issue is that within the IAM&Admin page the usage is shown as zero.

Comment: It is strange that the usage is shown as zero. Maybe you can sum total_bytes_processed grouped by user_email in your query. That might give you a brief idea about how many bytes are scanned.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did this already. Unfortunately what I still miss is seeing at a specific point in time, how much I have "left". I noticed that for the project billing is not enabled, as I needed to start with the "free" limit. Can this be a reason?

Comment: Yes, that might be the reason. Additionally, if you know the quota, in Cloud Monitoring, you can set the threshold value to the quota value and see how much you have left.

Comment: Could you specify this a bit more? I don't understand the metrics that exist for the quota. I can see 4 different ones. Two of them I tried already (see above question) but I did not understand what I'm looking at as they don't have a y-axis label on them.